# Does database role permissions take precedence over schema/object level permissions?

Tags: sql-server

I had an interesting observation on SQL Server security permissions.

My Setup is as below. I am trying to restrict user from updating tables under specific schema.

Problem statement is **Why user is allowed to do inserts on table through view (of different schema) even though insert is explicitly denied on schema of table in view definition?**

```
USE master
GO

CREATE LOGIN Login1
    WITH password = 'Admin@123'
GO

CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO

USE TestDB
GO

CREATE user Login1
FROM LOGIN Login1
GO

CREATE SCHEMA sch1
GO

CREATE SCHEMA V
GO

CREATE TABLE sch1.table1 (
    id INT
    ,name VARCHAR(5)
    )
GO

CREATE VIEW v.view1
AS
SELECT *
FROM sch1.table1
GO

CREATE VIEW sch1.view2
AS
SELECT *
FROM sch1.table1
GO

--User can update all tables
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [Login1] 
GO

--Except tables under this schema
DENY INSERT
    ON SCHEMA::[sch1]
    TO [Login1]
GO



--Open session with Login1
USE TestDB
GO

--Should not work, does not work.
INSERT sch1.table1
SELECT 1, 'A'
--The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'table1', database 'TestDB', schema 'sch1'.


--Should not work, does not work.
INSERT sch1.view2
SELECT 1, 'A'
--The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'view2', database 'TestDB', schema 'sch1'.


-- Works! - even though write is denied on underlying table?
INSERT v.view1
SELECT 1, 'A'
--(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view?view=sql-server-ver16#Permissions), I would expect the insert through view to fail as well.

> Requires UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE permissions on the target table, depending on the action being performed.

But it works because of a concept called **Ownership chaining**. [Official tutorial is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-ownership-chains-and-context-switching?view=sql-server-ver16)

When you have access to one object (in this case *v.view1*) and that object references a securable with the same owner (*sch1.table1*), then the permissions are not checked at all.

Since both objects have no explicit owner:

> by default, schema-contained objects are owned by the schema owner

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(objects_TSQL)%3Bk(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1)%3Bk(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1)%3Bk(MiscellaneousFilesProject)%3Bk(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20schema%2Dcontained%20objects%20are%20owned%20by%20the%20schema%20owner:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20schema%2Dcontained%20objects%20are%20owned%20by%20the%20schema%20owner)

and schema owner can be found here

```
SELECT
    s.name AS schName, dp.name AS ownerUser
FROM sys.schemas AS s 
JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
    ON dp.principal_id = s.principal_id
WHERE s.name IN (N'v', N'sch1')
```

[image]

You can break the ownership chain by changing the owner of the schema *v* like this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::v TO Login1
```

Then you'll get the DENY you expect.